# Python - Displaying a web site in the same browser tab each time webbrowser.open is called

Tags: python, html, python-webbrowser, browser-tab

In Python, I would like to initially open a new browser tab and display a web site. The program will be displaying other png images before cycling back to displaying the web site again. It's like a slide show. I tried to use the webbrowser.open statement displayed below to open the web site with the "New" parameter equaling 1 expecting a new tab not to be opened, but every time webbrowser.open is called, a new tab opens on the Chrome browser.

Can you tell me what coding is needed to ensure once a tab is opened in the browser, additional calls to webbrowser.open won't open new tabs for the web site?

```
webbrowser.open('https://mawaqit.net/en/abricc-acton-01720-united-states', new=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with the webbrowser tool, but using selenium webdriver the following all stays in the same tab.

```
# import
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# browser setup
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(10)

# open url
browser.get("http://www.google.com")

# click element on page (same tab)
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a").click()

# open new URL (same tab)
browser.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

Also, some other tools available in selenium are below. These are useful if you want new tabs but need to switch back and forth to "parent" tabs:

```
# assign tab variables (window_handle = tab apparently)
window = browser.current_window_handle
parent = browser.window_handles[0]
child = browser.window_handles[1]

# switch to new tab
browser.switch_to.window(parent)
```

I hope that at least some element of this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the useful coding. Using selenium worked for us after I found out how to install it and get hold of the chrome driver and added its locations in the Mac's path.

Answer (score 2):

the docs says

> webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)
> Display url using the
> default browser. If new is 0, the url is opened in the same browser
> window if possible. If new is 1, a new browser window is opened if
> possible. If new is 2, a new browser page (“tab”) is opened if
> possible. If autoraise is True, the window is raised if possible (note
> that under many window managers this will occur regardless of the
> setting of this variable).

Nothing here says that it can replace or close the current tab, so I am afraid that you will have to use something like Selenium instead.